# How do I avoid overcharging the inverter battery and keep it healthy

Tags: electrical, battery, inverter, power-backup, fire-safety

I have installed the Luminous Inverter Battery (lead acid) as power back up for essential electrical appliances at home.

There is not much electricity cut. I just want to be sure that I'm not overcharging the battery.

I don't understand the below [instruction](https://www.luminousindia.com/blog/post/hazards-of-lead-acid-battery-emission-of-harmful-gases.html)

**Avoid overcharging the battery and ensure to regular discharge of the battery if power cut is very minimal and battery power is used very rarely**.

So should I be turning off the main switch once in a month for half a day? so the power in battery discharges?

Can someone help me understand this please ?

P.S.

Can someone also recommend me the right gas detector for lead acid batteries please?

Comment: Most good(not the cheapest in store) battery chargers should read battery charge and turn off.  Good ventilation, fan blowing in and a fan blowing out in a room, will be better and cheaper than a gas detector.  A battery tester will help for checking battery charge.

Comment: discharging once a month is a bit much, maybe once every 3-4 months. It would also help if you can keep them less than fully charged, which is paradoxical but yields a longer shelf life. If you don't need the full capacity, floating them at 80% will be a lot better than 99%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lead-acid batteries should be charged to a lower voltage for "float" duty, which is basically what you are describing.

2.25V/cell @25°C, or 13.5V for a typical 6 cell "12V" battery. Reduce per-cell voltage by 0.003V (3 millivolts) per °C for higher battery temperatures, or increase for lower battery temperatures.

If the battery charger provided does not understand that, it will cost you some batteries.

Hydrogen is the gas that lead-acid batteries give off when gassing. Ventilation is required.

Inexpensive UPS's (which are a battery, inverter, and a battery charger) are often terrible at this, and kill batteries frequently by keeping them overcharged.